# Parse list of e-mails using perl one-liner

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I'm trying to automate one thing and currenty met the following issue.

I have a list of e-mails in such format:

```
John Doe <John.Doe@example.com>; Bill Gates <Bill.Gates@example.com>; Alfred Pennyworth <Alfred.Pennyworth@example.com>; (etc.)
```

I need to parse this and provide as list of recipients to `mailx` separated by commas. This code not giving desired output.

```
perl -wne'while(/[\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\w+/g){print "$&,"}' $MAIL_LIST
```

It appends comma after the last parsed e-mail (eg. "**Alfred.Pennyworth@example.com,**") while I need commas only between them.

Comment: is input multi lines?

Comment: @mpapec , no, it's single line. I have no problems with multi-line input, but customer provides list of e-mails in single line (standart Outlook format). Solution is already provided in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join list of regex matches with `,`

```
perl -wne 'print join ",", /([\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\w+)/g' $MAIL_LIST
```

Answer (score 2):

use this, print `,` before each email address except the first one

```
 perl -wne'$c=0;while(/[\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\w+/g){print "," if $c++;print "$&"}'
```